# Perl find and replace backlashes in text file

Tags: perl, file, edit, backslash

I have a file that I am entering into a MySQL table. The file, sadly, contains double quotes (") and backslashes (). I have figured out a way, in Perl, to find and replace the double quotes (or so I think), but can't seem to figure out how to remove all the silly backslashes.

Does anyone have any ideas? Here is what the snippet looks like... sorry I am such a noob I am still learning!

```
open(FILE,$fileName) || die("Cannot Open File");
my(@fcont) = <FILE>;
close FILE;

my $searchStr1=qq{"};
my $replaceStr1=qq{ };

open(FOUT,">$fileName") || die("Cannot Open File");
foreach $line (@fcont) {
    $line =~ s/$searchStr1/$replaceStr1/g;
    print FOUT $line;
}

#not sure if searching for backslash will work
my $searchStr2="\\";
my $replaceStr2=qq{ };

open(FOUT,">$fileName") || die("Cannot Open File");
foreach $line (@fcont) {
    $line =~ s/$searchStr2/$replaceStr2/g;
    print FOUT $line;
}

close FOUT;
```

Comment: When replacing backslashes, you have to consider double quoting issues. Put the match pattern directly into the `s///` operator to remove any such possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the search pattern in a double-quoted variable, you need to double up on the backslashes:

```
my $searchStr2="\\\\";
```

The variable will then contain `\\`, so the regexp still gets two backslashes, the first one escaping the second one so that it will match a literal backslash.

Answer (score 1):

replace " or \ with blank

```
$line =~ s/"|\\/ /g;
```

Answer (score 1):

When substituting one literal string for another, it is more efficient to use [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) instead of `s///g`:

```
$line =~ tr{"\\}{' };
```